# How to split the rows and import into database in a big .CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, loops, csv, split

I have very big .csv file, it's consists of 1000 rows. While importing into my database it's taking too much time and sometimes it display error like **Time Out**.

To avoid this I want read first 100 rows and import into database, and so on. How to do in PHP ?. Is there any easy method available?

Comment: I have imported CSV with over 100,000 rows using `LOAD DATA INFILE` query. It's pretty fast. But if PHP times out, then increase your `max_execution_time`

Answer (score 1):

You sould probably consider using MySQL [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) syntax.
It allows you, from a SQL query, to import data from a CSV in a table. You can parameter delimiter, line endings, etc...
It could be much faster than parsing the file in PHP and generating INSERT's.
Note that you have two options : LOAD DATA INFILE (file must be readable by mysql deamon) and LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE (file must be readable from mysql client).

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000, ",")) != FALSE) 
                {
                    $num = count($data); 
                    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
                    {
                      $col[$c] = $data[$c];
                    }
     }
```

this code will be help for you